# What is the real point of using content security policy (CSP)?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I’ve read all the official motivations why it’s the best thing since sliced bread, but really, if it can be disabled and/or changed by browser extensions, browser settings or even by browser default settings/configurations/functions/properties or by proxies?

If someone truly wants to target your site, why wouldn’t they disable it or use a custom way to connect to your site?

Sorry about this not being a specific code problem. It’s rather me wondering why one should even bother with implementing this in first place? Lord knows the syntax is less than trivial and there are serious lack of functionality that leaves you choosing between allowing risky behavior or limiting site functionality with no way of retaining functionality in a secure manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If someone truly wants to target your site, why wouldn’t they disable it or use a custom way to connect to your site?

They might, but that’s not what CSP protects against.

A lot of site hacks go something like this: Bad Guy hacks site. Innocent Victim accesses site, and gets hit by Bad Guy’s payload.  CSP works to protect Victim in that case, not as much to prevent Bad Guy from getting in. (Other security measures take care of the initial attack.)

Also note that “Victim” can be your site, if you draw functionality from a third party site (e.g. PayPal or Google), because if one of those guys get hacked, CSP on your site can say “hey, that’s not allowed”.  There was a big hack of a service provider (forgetting who) a couple months ago that hit a ton of sites because they were all drawing code from that one site. Client sites could have prevented victimizing their customers with a single line of CSP that would have recognized the providers code was not valid

Comment: But if "Bad Guy hacks site" they maybe also changes the CSP as they want.
I mean, if someone can chage the payload they probably can also change the CSP HTTP header to make it valid.

Comment: @Alex75 Depends on the hack. Maybe they just manage to inject some JavaScript. Which won’t run because it (for example) lacks the CSP nonce

Answer (score 0):

Every security tools, guideline and policy do solve different problems on various context.

For example, proxy could rewrite.
But there are TLS/SSL/encryption to fight against Man-in-middle.

For example, browser/plugin could rewrite content.
There are anti-virus. And it is not a problem they are running on the client computer already.

(You don't lock the gate for safely if a thief is already in your house)

CSP fight against one problem - Untrusted content from a trusted source.
Third party/user generated content on a website you trust.

For example.
If anyone upload a picture or javascript to e.g. eBay, amazon or any online shop with payment gateway, neither the service host or end-user would like them to be executed to steal your password, to steal login cookie, or to redirect you to a phishing site.